# How to get offsetTop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get offsetTop using react and then add those values to redux store.

My component is as follows :

```
export const refs = {
    home: "home",
    whyUs: "whyUs",
    concessionAutohandle: "concessionAutohandle",
    performance: "performance",
    benefits: "benefits",
    whoAreWe: "whoAreWe",
    contact: "contact"
};

class HomePage extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        let offsets = {
            [refs.home]: this.refs[refs.home].offsetTop,
            [refs.whyUs]: this.refs[refs.whyUs].offsetTop,
            [refs.concessionAutohandle]: this.refs[refs.concessionAutohandle].offsetTop + 300,
            [refs.performance]: this.refs[refs.performance].offsetTop,
            [refs.benefits]: this.refs[refs.benefits].offsetTop,
            [refs.whoAreWe]: this.refs[refs.whoAreWe].offsetTop,
            [refs.contact]: this.refs[refs.contact].offsetTop
        };

        this.props.actions.addOffsets(offsets);

    }

    render(){
        const languageHome = this.props.currentLanguage.default;

        return (
            <div className="homeMain" ref={refs.home}>
                <section className="marginOnXs" style={{width: '100%', padding: 0}}>
                    <MainSlider />
                </section>

                <section id="whyUs" ref={refs.whyUs} className="why-us" style={{paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0}}>
                    <Info currentLanguage={languageHome} />
                </section>


                <section id="concessionAutohandle" ref={refs.concessionAutohandle} className="" style={{paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0}}>
                    <ConcessionAutohandle currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
                </section>

                <div className="clearfix"></div>

                <section id="performance" ref={refs.performance} className="" style={{paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0}}>
                    <Performance currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
                    <div className="clearfix"></div>
                </section>

                <div className="clearfix"></div>

                <section id="benefits" ref={refs.benefits} className="benefits noPadding">
                    <Benefits currentLanguage={languageHome} authenticated={this.props.authenticated}/>
                    <div className="clearfix"></div>
                </section>

                <section id="whoAreWe" ref={refs.whoAreWe} className="whoAreWe noPadding">
                    <WhoAreWe currentLanguage={languageHome} />
                    <div className="clearfix"></div>
                </section>

                 <section id="contactSection" name="contact" className="contactSection" ref={refs.contact}>
                        <ContactForm currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
                 </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);
```

When the page first time loads, everything work fine. Those values are correct.

The problem is if I navigate to a new route, registration page in my case.

When I click on a link to go to the registration page I have two problems :

1. The focus on the registration page is somewhere in the middle (offsetTop is 420) of the page and not on top like it should be
2. If I then click on the logo to go back to the home page, those values in componentDidMount are not correct, they have a values almost twice higher than the previous values. That is not correct, they need to be the same.

I also tried with `let rectCollection = object.getClientRects();` in componentDidMount to get offsetTop, bit the problem is the same.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `offset` assigning logic as a function and call that function on `componentDidUpdate()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()`. Something like below

```
function setOffset() {
  let offsets = {
            [refs.home]: this.refs[refs.home].offsetTop,
            [refs.whyUs]: this.refs[refs.whyUs].offsetTop,
            [refs.concessionAutohandle]: this.refs[refs.concessionAutohandle].offsetTop + 300,
            [refs.performance]: this.refs[refs.performance].offsetTop,
            [refs.benefits]: this.refs[refs.benefits].offsetTop,
            [refs.whoAreWe]: this.refs[refs.whoAreWe].offsetTop,
            [refs.contact]: this.refs[refs.contact].offsetTop
        };

        this.props.actions.addOffsets(offsets);
 }

componentDidMount(){
 this.setOffset()
}

componentWillReceiveProps(){
 this.setOffset()
}
```

Comment: Nope, the same problem.